# How to attach navbar only on certain pages using ui-router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-include

How to display a navbar on every page except landingpage, so that not have to attach a navbar file on each of needed pages? Now I have enclosed navbar on main app layout, how it should be handled to keep it DRY?

Demo (with navbar on each page):

```js
var App = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    .state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      templateUrl: 'about.html'
    }).state('landingpage', {
      url: '/landingpage',
      templateUrl: 'landingpage.html'
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-include="'navbar.html'"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="navbar.html">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="landingpage">LandingPage</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
        <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <h1>The About Page</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="landingpage.html">
    <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: *In general, my way is to use few families of Hierarchies. E.g. Entities are having root/list/detail, while login has no hierarchy. Documentations can share root but end with root.doc... This way we can share lot of code, while still having ability to distinguish (by logical "families")...*

Comment: Set boolean value in your controller with respect to your $stateProvider state.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Created named views like `<div ui-view name="nav"></div>` and set the templateUrl by view by state. For the `landingpage` state, just don't provide a templateUrl for the `nav` view and it won't render the navbar.

**Update**: hide on `landingpage` not `home` state.

```js
var App = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);
App.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      views: {
        nav: {
          templateUrl: 'navbar.html'
        },
        content: {
          templateUrl: 'home.html'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('about', {
      url: '/about',
      views: {
        nav: {
          templateUrl: 'navbar.html'
        },
        content: {
          templateUrl: 'about.html'
        }
      } 
    }).state('landingpage', {
      url: '/landingpage',
      views: {
        content: {
          templateUrl: 'landingpage.html'
        }
      } 
    });
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ui-view name="nav"></div>

  <div class="container">
    <div ui-view name="content"></div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="navbar.html">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" ui-sref="landingpage">LandingPage</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
        <li ng-hide="signedIn()"><a href="/login">Log In</a></li>
        <li ng-show="signedIn()"><a ng-click="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1>The Homey Page</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <h1>The About Page</h1>
  </script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="landingpage.html">
    <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
  </script>
</div>
```