# Toggle menu based on route/page - Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a website where I am using typescript, angularjs, bootstrap.

On some of my pages I have top menu and some pages I have both sidebar and top menu (once the user logs in)

I am using ui-router for routes.

How can I show sidebar menu on certain pages and hide it on others?

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104893/angular-ui-router-how-to-create-a-layout-state

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576063/how-to-attach-navbar-only-on-certain-pages-using-ui-router/29577344#29577344