# how to include different nav panels with ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have two sections to my AngularJS app which need separate nav bars:

- **`Patents`**

  - `patent nav bar: list patents, add patents`
- **`Transactions`**

  - `transaction nav bar: current transactions, transaction history`

I have read [How to attach navbar only on certain pages using ui-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576063/how-to-attach-navbar-only-on-certain-pages-using-ui-router), where you can use views, but that is including the `templateUrl` in the state, where I have my `templateUrl` declared in the component like so:

```
$stateProvider
.state('patents', {
   url: '/patents',
   component: 'patents',
})

angular.module('myApp').component('patents', {
    bindings: { patents: '<' },
    templateUrl: '../templates/patents/list/list-patents.htm'
});
```

***Question***

What is the best approach to include different navigation in my templates/states when using components in `ui-router`? Apologies if the answer is straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1**

Through `ng-include` in your template:

```
<div ng-include="'link/to/template.html'"></div>
```

---

**Method 2**

More dynamically, you can create a custom `<navigation>` component, which sets the correct template through a `$stateParam`.

Router:

```
.state('patents', {
    url         : '/patents',
    component   : 'patents',
    params      : {
        navigation  : 'custom'
    }
})
```

And then, in your navigation component, you can use

```
template    : function($stateParams) {
    var navigation = $stateParam.navigation || 'default';
    return '<div ng-include="\''link/to/' + navigation + '.html'\'"></div>
},
```

So you only have to set the `param` in your router when there is a custom navigation for that page.

Make sure though to include `<navigation>` on every page.

---

**Method 3**

In case you don't want to include `<navigation>` on every page, you can also create a single navigation menu (like you probably have now), and add a controller, with the following method

```
app.controller('NavigationCtrl', function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        this.navigation = toParams.navigation;
    });
})
```

The you can capture the `toParams` on every route update, and use that to dynamically change the template:

Navigation template:

```
<div class="nav" ng-controller="NavigationCtrl as $ctrl">

    <div ng-if="$ctrl.navigation === 'default'">
        // Include default
    </div>

    <div ng-if="$ctrl.navigation === 'custom'">
        // Include custom
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Bare with me whilst I give this a go

Comment: Sure, let me know! Make sure to include the `<navigation>` component on every page though, because the `template` function is only called once (on load).

Comment: I've updated with a third way (through a `controller`). I'm sure one of those should work, but let me know if you run into problems.

Comment: How am I accessing the navigation component in your method 2?

Comment: You have to create it yourself through `app.component('navigation', { ... })`, now the html element `<navigation></navigation>` is available in your templates.

Comment: Ahhhhh, like an idiot I didn't include a link in my `index.html`. Nearly there, got a new error. Will accept as soon as I finished

Comment: Nice. No problem, glad to help!